# Combining two sets of comma separated values from ajax and inserting into MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating two sets of comma-separated values, `studentids`, and `marks`. I am then sending these two sets of data to a PHP file which then inserts the values into the database.

For example, if `studentids` is `1,4,5,7,2` and `marks` is `24,25,25,50,50`, then I want it inserted into a database with the structure `id |  studentid  |  mark` as:

```
id |  studentid  |  mark
 1 |      1      |   24
 2 |      4      |   25
 3 |      5      |   25
 4 |      7      |   50
 5 |      2      |   50
```

My jQuery / AJAX looks like this:

```
var marks= $(".inpmark").map(function(){return $(this).val()}).get();
var studentids= $(".studidsub").map(function() {return $(this).text()}).get();

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "modules/addmarks.php",
dataType: 'json',
data: {s:studentids,m:marks},
cache: false,
})  
... etc
```

I know how to add values if one set of values is comma-separated by doing a `foreach` like this in my PHP file:

```
... (excerpt)
if( !$errors ) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `marks` (`studentid`, `mark`) VALUES (?,?)";
    $stmts = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $student_ids = explode(",",$studentids);

    foreach ($student_ids as $student_id) {
        $stmts->bind_param('ii',$student_id,$mark);
        $result = $stmts->execute();
    }
$returnResult = "Success";
}
```

Comment: They aren't comma separated...you are sending arrays. Beyond that it's really not clear what specific problem is

Answer (score 0):

```
if( !$errors ) {
$sql = "INSERT INTO `marks` (`studentid`, `mark`) VALUES (?,?)";
$stmts = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$student_ids = explode(",",$studentids);
$mark = explode(",",$marks);
$i=0;
foreach ($student_ids as $student_id) {
    $stmts->bind_param('ii',$student_id,$mark[$i]);
    $result = $stmts->execute();
    $i++;
}
$returnResult = "Success";
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.